Filtering out messages using tracing_subscriber::filter::Directive
I'm trying to filter out the PartitionEOF error log messages that the rdkafka crate produces when you have enable.partition.eof set to true.
We're using the tracing and tracing-subscriber traits for logging.
The log messages look like this:
{
    "timestamp": ...,
    "level": "ERROR",
    "fields": {
        "message": "librdkafka: Global error: PartitionEOF (Broker: No more messages): Fetch from broker 1 reached end of partition at offset ... (HighwaterMark ...)",
        "log.target": "rdkafka::client",
        ...
    },
    "target": "rdkafka::client",
    "threadId": ...
}

As I understand from the tracing-subscriber documentation, I should be able to do something like this:
    let filter = EnvFilter::from_default_env()
        .add_directive("rdkafka::client[{message=\"librdkafka: Global error: PartitionEOF.*\"}]=off".parse().unwrap());

    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .json()
        .with_env_filter(filter)
        .with_thread_ids(true)
        .init();

However, that filter isn't working. And futhermore, I can't get any filter to work where I specify the value for a message.
For example, suppose I have the following:
    let filter = EnvFilter::from_default_env()
        .add_directive("[{message=\"asdf\"}]=off".parse().unwrap());

    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .json()
        .with_env_filter(filter)
        .with_thread_ids(true)
        .init();

    info!("asdf");

... in that case, the "asdf" message is not filtered out.
Similarly, changing the filter to "[{message=asdf}]=off" does not filter out the "asdf" log message.
However, changing the filter to "[{message}]=off" does filter the message.
What's going on here? Why is specifying a value not working as per the syntax described in the documentation?
target[span{field=value}]=level


Looks like value filter only works for span-level fields. Events fields are not checked. Not sure if this is a bug or by design, but I didn't find anything about this behavior in the docs. See this issue in tracing-subscriber repo.

Is off the right term here? I don't see it mentioned in the tracing_subscriber documentation anywhere
https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/filter/struct.EnvFilter.html
